# How to speed up the cyclic F-modifier?

Tags: animation

i'm relatively new with Blender.  I'm creating a repeating animation with a cyclic F-modifier.  However I want to make the cycle go faster after a period of time.

Say I want to make the cycle go faster at frame 1500, but I can't find a way to do it.  I have searched anywhere but couldn't find what I am looking for.

Any help would be appericated.

Thanks!

I have tried your suggestion.  However the animation becomes choppy when I shorten the cycle I duplicated.  Here's a clip - it snapped to frame one when going fast. (I set the scale to .500 in the playack setting.)  If I did it wrong, please let me know, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Bake one cycle to animation then in NLA, duplicate the animation as many times as desired and scale instance of animation to "accelerate" it at the desired time?

Comment: How do I bake a cycle to animation?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/actions.html#bake-action

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll try it out.

Comment: Does anyone here know how to fix this problem?